# zf2 naming conventions of classes

Tags: zend-framework2

What kind of name do you use for classes? For Example an user service located in the folder User/Service with the namespace User\Service:

1. class User
2. class UserService

First i prevered using the first option because of the directory, its clear that it is a service. But then i saw the following using my service in for example a controller.

```
namespace User\Controller;

use User\Service\User;

class UserController {
    public function __construct(User $userService) {
        ...
    }
}
```

At first glance you think you have to inject an user entity to the constructor. Or should i change the use statement to **use User\Service\User as UserService**? Are there any conventions?

Answer (score 2):

This is subjective, but I normally use `User\Service\UserService` for the reasons you describe. With namespaces, you rarely use the full class name, and if you have multiple 'User' classes, it gets a bit confusing, and you end up having to alias everything anyway.

I've seen `UserService` used more than the other way, but it's just down to personal preference really.